# MySQL: SQL to remove country code from phone number

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL table `[customers]`, I have a phone column `[phone]` that has phone numbers in this format:

```
[phone] = [+ sign][country code][space][number]
```

The `[number]` part can be in any format:

```
1234567890
123.456.7890
123 456 7890
(123) 456 7890
```

etc.

But the full phone number  column value `[phone]` always start with `[+ sign][country code][space]`

Example:

`[phone]` values are:

```
+1 888-888-8888
+1 888.888 (8888)
+31 104232385
+33 143375100
+31 10 423 2385
+33 1 43 37 51 00
```

I want to remove the country code: `[+ sign][country code][space]` from all phone numbers `[phone]`

Example:

```
+1 888-888-8888    =  888-888-8888
+1 888.888 (8888)  =  888.888 (8888)
+31 104232385      =  104232385
+33 143375100      =  143375100
+31 10 423 2385    =  10 423 2385
+33 1 43 37 51 00  =  1 43 37 51 00
```

What I want is to remove all leading characters till first space in the column. Which will always be: `[+ sign][country code]`

Or in other words: Remove everything before the first occurrence of certain character: `[space]` in MySQL?

What would be the query for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to do a regex replacement:

```sql
UPDATE customers
SET phone = REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '^\\+[0-9]+ ', '');
```

### Demo

If you're using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, then we can use the base string functions as a workaround:

```sql
UPDATE customers
SET phone = SUBSTR(phone, INSTR(phone, ' ') + 1)
WHERE phone LIKE '+%';
```

### Demo